# Reuse markup from react component in single-page, client-side only webapp

Tags: reactjs

React relies on the `data-react-checksum` attribute for reusing markup, which is only set in `renderComponentToString` (used for server-side rendering of components).

How can I reuse the react-component markup when the component is rendered client-side only?

#### Background

I'm working on a client-side only webapp. One of the project's goals is to render as quickly as possible, reducing UI "lag" from uninitialized elements, JS loading/parsing, and so forth.

I'm want to cache the rendered react-components markup using localStorage so the previous UI state can be restored as early as possible (again for performance reasons without waiting ~200ms for react to be loaded and parsed).

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, there's no way to turn a string of markup into a live React component (at least not in a performant way). Plus, it doesn't really make sense as your component might have had hidden state that aren't shown on the final rendered DOM string. If you try to revert the string into a component, it'll lead to state inconsistencies.

Something neat to do is to serialize your data into localStorage, and then reproduce your components from that data. But this more or less helps in your case.

But still, you can roll your own small logic on putting the string markup, then letting React destroy it subsequently by rendering a second time.

Comment: Well, I don't want to generate the react component from the markup. React supports [server-generated markup](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendercomponenttostring) and I would like to use this capability, but client side only.

I already have logic that caches the markup and restores it on page load, however react destroys the markup and creates it anew, since `data-react-checksum` is missing.

Comment: You can still use renderComponentToString on client side. When you renderComponent the same thing on top of it, it works correctly without thrashing the markup.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. But then the component is rendered twice, once for caching and once for displaying. Somethign I wanted to avoid